# Replace spaces with bullet signs with plain css

Tags: html, css, text

I wanted to add the **bullet sign (•)** instead of the spaces to separate words; this could be easy to achieve with JavaScript but can we do this with plain CSS?

Here's the code:

```
<p class="text">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<!-- the styled text should be like "lorem•ipsum•dolor•sit•amet" -->

<style>

p.text {
  /* style */
}

</style>
```

Comment: No, it's can't be done with CSS alone

Comment: I suppose you could do something with `unicode-range` to sub out the "space character` for an asterisk of another font. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range but I'm doubtful that actually works.

Comment: @Paulie_D could you please give a rough idea by submitting an answer?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. It's meant to substitute one font for another for a specific character, not change one character into another.

Comment: Ok it's fine, thanks for your efforts. I guess this cannot be implemented with css only.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way that comes to my mind is using HTML entity code for bullet circle `&bull;`, which you insert between each word. So no CSS needed just HTML. Not sure if that's helpful for you.

You can do it like so:

```
<p class="text">lorem&bull;ipsum&bull;dolor&bull;sit&bull;amet</p>
```

and you would get:

lorem•ipsum•dolor•sit•amet

Comment: I want it do be done by CSS rather than manual insertion of the bullet character in HTML as the text can also be user generated or there may be too much of text to add the `&bull` after each single word.

Comment: sounds like you need some JS then.. as far as my knowledge goes there's no way to do this just with CSS